# await not working in release build with react-native@0.50.1

Tags: react-native, async-await

await is working in the debug build but not in the release build. This happens with react-native@0.50.1 but not with react-native@0.48.4. It happens on device and on simulators. I see the first log but not the second:

```
console.log('before await')
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
console.log('after await value: ' + value)
```

I tried with different build settings for dead code stripping, bitcode and performance optimization, but it didn't help.

What can be the reason? Maybe something with babel? Or do I have to adapt the code to use "then"?

```
AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(...
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have the exact problem, it works just fine on emulator but after generating app in apk, it's not working anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I resolved it updating to:

- "react": "16.2.0"
- "react-native": "0.52.0"

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html